# no array operation allowed on element parameter of link function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-directive

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, model)
```

this is a link function for angular directive.

when i look into element object it has following structure

```
[<input google-place type=​"text" id=​"existingAreas" class=​"form-control      ng-isolate-scope" place=​"newProperty.address.selectedArea" country=​"in">​]
```

console.log(element) gives this

```
R[1]
0: input#existingAreas.form-control.ng-isolate-scope
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

It looks like it is an array. But when I try to do array operation like pop on it, it gives error. While reference to element[0] works.

I am unable to understand why it happens so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) we can see that:

> element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.

jQuery (and as such jqLite) return what are known as *array-like* objects which means that they have numerically indexed properties and a length property.  These look like arrays, and can be used with some array functions via the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function, but they are not true arrays and thus do not have normal array methods.

To get the last element, you can simply do

```
var last = element[element.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an object, you can not do array operations on it. If you need to remove keys from object try

```
delete element[0]
```

or

```
delete element.key
```

or

```
delete element['key']
```

Comment: why do you think this is not an object of array? I dont want to remove anything. I want to fetch the last element without using magic number